# jQuery(...).yiiActiveForm is not a function

Tags: php, yii2

Ошибка, как её убрать?

```
jQuery(...).yiiActiveForm is not a function
```

Я использую `Pjax` и нужно сменить версию `jQuery`, для этого я отключаю версию по умолчанию:

```
'bundles' => [
   'yii\web\JqueryAsset' => false, //отключаем генерацию по умолчанию JQuery
],
```

Подключаю `jQuery` в `layouts`:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/basic/web/assets/build/js/js_min/lib/Jquery/jquery-2.2.2.min.js"></script>
```

Пробовал подключать через `AssetBundle` и `$this->registerJsFile('url/to/file.js',  ['position' => yii\web\View::POS_HEAD]);`

Все работает отлично до тех пор, пока я не перехожу в `view` модуля. Но `layout` `main` - один, общий на всё приложение.

Если в `View` модуля еще подключить:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/basic/web/assets/build/js/js_min/lib/Jquery/jquery-2.2.2.min.js"></script>
```

Но скрипты все будут работать. Но та ошибка все равно возникает.

Похоже что в `Yii2 2.5` такого нету, а в новой есть.

Приложение/Эксперемены/Отчеты

---

### 1.Попытка , пытаемся добавить (**отрицательный результа**т)

```
'components' => [
    'assetManager' => [
    'class' => 'yii\web\AssetManager',
    'appendTimestamp' => true, //Включаем поддержку версионности
        'bundles' => [
            'yii\web\JqueryAsset' => [
                'sourcePath' => null,   // do not publish the bundle
                'js' => [
                    'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js',
                ]
            ],
        ],
    'linkAssets' => false, //генерация прямых ссылок на файлы, без копирование ресурсов
    ],
],
```

---

### 2.Попытка (**положительный результат**)

Архириктура нашего приложения:

1.Наше приложение имеет один модуль, у которого нету собственного layout, а по дефолту все его view будут отображаться в базовом layout самого оприложения (у меня он main.php).

2.Мы используем JQueryPjax, не тот Pjax которые установлен в Yii2 по дуфолту.

3.Подключение JQuery, мы делаем в layout main.php, в самом низу

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div id="pjax-container">
        <?= $content ?>
    </div>
</div>

   <script type="text/javascript" src="/basic/web/assets/build/js/js_min/lib/Jquery/jquery-2.2.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/basic/web/assets/build/js/js_min/lib/Pjax/jquery.pjax-min.js"></script>

<?php $this->endBody() ?>
</body>
</html>
<?php $this->endPage() ?>
```

4.Если мы уберем css класс **wrap**, то опять будет появлятсья ошибка, когда мы будем переходит в View модуля. Если убирать этот класс не будем, то и ошибки не будет. **Почему?**

**Новые данные**

CSS класс ни при чем!  Играет роль только div . То есть, если его не будет, будет ошибка.**Почему?**

Comment: @jQuery штатный JQuery мне не нужен, и я его отключаю , версия не та.

Comment: @MasterAlex Я ответил вам.

Answer (score 1):

Поменять версию `jQuery` можно в файле конфигурации:

```
return [
    // ...
    'components' => [
        'assetManager' => [
            'bundles' => [
                'yii\web\JqueryAsset' => [
                    'sourcePath' => null,   // отключение дефолтного jQuery
                    'js' => [
                        '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js', // добавление вашей версии
                    ]
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
];
```

Взято из [официальной документации](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-assets.html#customizing-asset-bundles)

Comment: А у вас работает этот код из офф документации? Выкладываю свой код компонента в свой  вопрос.

Comment: А почему код из офф документации должен не работать? Сейчас добавил это код в свой рабочий проект и всё в порядке, вместо дефолтного jQuery 1.11.3 добавился 2.1.1

Comment: А вот если убрать "//" из ссылки, как это у вас в коде, то да, не работает

Comment: Я и так и так и так делал, и http добавлял, предварительно проверив что ресурс там есть. Вообщем , там не все так просто. Я дефолтный сонтроллер переопределил на свой, и когда я Не отключаю Jquery, который генерируется по умолчанию, заходя в view, модуля, всё работает отлично, но, когда я захожу в view основного приложения, то Jquery не генерируется. Очень странно... Сейчася еще одну сборку скачаю, где всё установленно по дефолту, и буду проверять там.

Comment: Да, работает в чистой версии Yii2 , в последний стаблильной. Блоя.... Так почему не работает у меня , там где у меня расположен проект. Продолжаю тестировать..... Отпишу результаты. Чувствую это связанно с дефорлным контроллером.

Comment: @gilo1212, посмотрите расположение получившихся файлов скриптов, `JQuery` должен быть до каких-либо скриптов, по умолчанию он под футером, и если вы добавляете скрипты с использованием `JQuery` выше в `HTML` структуре, то этот js-код не будет видеть `JQuery`

Comment: Большое спасибо, Вам! Я уже получил положительный результат от своих исследований, но, конечный ответ, для меня остаётся загадкой.

Comment: обновил свой ответ номер - 2